# How to prevent dput from uploading *.orig.tar.gz again?

Tags: command-line, ppa, packaging, launchpad

When I upload a package to archive

```
$ dput ppa:mylaunchpadid/myppa.ppa mypackage1.0-0ubuntu2_source.changes
Checking signature on .changes
gpg: Signature made ...
gpg: Good signature from ...
Good signature on ...source.changes
Good signature on ....dsc.
Package includes an .orig.tar.gz file although the debian revision suggests
that it might not be required. Multiple uploads of the .orig.tar.gz may be
rejected by the upload queue management software.
Uploading to ppa (via sftp to ppa.launchpad.net):
```

How to prevent uploading **orig.tar.gz** every time I upload a revision?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To prevent `dput` from uploading (again) your **orig.tar.gz** file you need to remove it  from the `source.changes` file.

To do so, you basically have to change your call to the build command to add the `-sd` option. It will force the exclusion of the original **orig.tar.gz** source.

From the `dpkg-genchanges` man pages:

> ```
>    -sd    Forces  the  exclusion  of the original source and includes only
>           the diff.
> ```

For the `dpkg-buildpackage` command:

```
$ dpkg-buildpackage -sd
```

For the `debuild` command:

```
$ debuild -sd
```

For the `pdebuild` command:

```
$ pdebuild --debbuildopts -sd
```

Comment: Note that it's quite possible `~/.devscripts` has the option `-sa` passed to debuild, which of course forces source upload, and it's bad to have that in there...

Comment: @ThomasW. Good to know, thanks for mentioning this possibility.